# Redux state not updating in requestAnimationFrame

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, requestanimationframe

When updating Redux state, the updated state is received in the component, but not within the `requestAnimationFrame` function.

i.e. we can log out the updated state (`backgroundMode`) near the top of the component declaration - updates are logged as expected:

```
const VideoCanvas = ({ videoRef }: IVideoCanvasProps) => {
  ...
  console.log("backgroundMode", backgroundMode);
  ...
```

But in the requestAnimationFrame function, only the initial value (`None`) is logged out for each frame.

```
  async function animate() {
    ...

    // Does not receive updates from Redux store
    console.log("animate backgroundMode", backgroundMode);
    
    ...

    animationFrame.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

The console output looks something like the following:

```
backgroundMode None
(20) VideoCanvas.tsx:71 animate backgroundMode None

// change dropdown to blur mode
VideoCanvas.tsx:26 backgroundMode Blur
(23) VideoCanvas.tsx:71 animate backgroundMode None

// change dropdown to mask mode
VideoCanvas.tsx:26 backgroundMode Mask
(62) VideoCanvas.tsx:71 animate backgroundMode None
```

Adding `backgroundMode` to the dependencies of the useEffect initiating the animation, only causes two animation threads to be spawned, worsening the problem. As it stands, this effect looks like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    animationFrame.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    return () => {
      if (animationFrame.current) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame.current);
      }
    };
  }, [bodyPixNet]);
```

The file in question can be viewed in full on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/ryanachten/Echo/blob/feature/background-effects/Client/src/components/VideoCanvas.tsx)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you explain a bit more, i didnt understood the question and error you getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of sounds like the old "stale state enclosure" issue happening in the `animate` function. Since you are recursively calling `requestAnimationFrame` and passing the value of `animate` from the render cycle the animations are started in, you may want to cache a copy of `backgroundMode` also in a ref so that it can be updated anytime, and also the current value can be read anytime. Use an `useEffect` hook to update the cache.

```
const backgroundModeRef = React.useRef(backgroundMode);

React.useEffect(() => {
  backgroundModeRef.current = backgroundMode;
}, [backgroundMode]);
```

In the `animate` function, refer to the cached ref value.

```
async function animate() {
  ...

  // Does not receive updates from Redux store
  console.log("animate backgroundMode", backgroundModeRef.current);

  ...

  animationFrame.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```